# Blur Effect when switching/closing Modals

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a durable blur effect on the background when I open/switch my modal by clicking a button.

What I have so far:

I have a button, on click it will open a bootstrap modal. In this modal you can click again on a button to switch to another modal, which means the first modal hides and the second one comes in. From the second modal you can switch back to the first or close it.

When I open the first modal by clicking the button, my background has the blur effect. If I close the modal by clicking the close button the blur effect will disappear. The effect disappears too when I click outside the modal, so the modal will close.

Code:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>
</button>
<section role="region">
    <div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                /* almost similar to loginModal */
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <header class="modal-header">
                        <div class="well">
                            <h2 class="modal-title">Login Formular</h2>
                        </div>
                    </header>
                    <article>
                        <div class="well modal-body">
                            /* Form */
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <a href="" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerModal">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

jQuery Code:

```
//Blur
$("button[data-target='#loginModal'], a[data-target='#registerModal'], a[data-target='#loginModal']").click(function() {
    $("#main").css({
        "filter": "blur(20px)",
        "transition": "all 0.75s ease-out"
    });
});
//Remove Blur
$(".modal .modal-footer button").click(function() {   $("#main").removeAttr("style"); });

$("#loginModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(e) { $("#main").removeAttr("style");    });
```

My problem is now that I don't have an idea how to apply a durable blur effect when I switch to the second modal, because the first modal will be closed then and the second one will be opened. My idea was that I have to check if both modals are closed, but couldn't get it done because I don't know if there is such a way.

Another thing is that I want to close the modal by clicking out of modal-dialog and end the blur effect. I attached an click event on body which removes the blur effect, but the problem there was that you can also click in the modal and it will remove the blur, because the body will be over the whole page...

```
$("#loginModal, #registerModal").on("show.bs.modal", function () {
    $("body").on("click", function(e) {
        $("#main").removeAttr("style");

        $("body").off("click");
    });
});
```

Maybe the problem is trivial or something, but I couldn't get it done. Hopefully there is someone who can help me out of this ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't `toggle` **AND** `dismiss` a modal at the same time.

I placed the two different "actions" on the same `click` handler:

1. Close the "other" modal
2. Open the target modal

About the `blur` effect on the main text, I placed it in a CSS class (cleaner code) and I used a "flag" to prevent it from being removed if a second modal is opening.

Also, I added a `#` in the `href` attribute of the glyphicon anchor, to prevent its behavior to load a page.

```js
//Blur
var removeBlur = true;
$("[data-target]").click(function(e) {

  removeBlur = false; // Set flag to false

  var thisTarget = $(this).data("target");  // Get the target modal id
  console.log( thisTarget );

  $(".modal" ).not(thisTarget).modal("hide"); // Hide the other modal

  $(thisTarget).modal("show");  // Show the "target" modal

  $("#main").addClass("blurred"); // Add the blurry effect

  setTimeout(function(){  // Wait 400ms to let the hidden.bs.modal the "false" removeBlur flag while it is set to false.
    removeBlur = true;  // reset flag
  },400)
});

//Remove Blur
//$(".modal .modal-footer button").click(function(){ $("#main").removeClass("blurred"); }); // This one is not needed.

$(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(e) { // On modal hide remove the blur effect if removeBlur flag is true
  if(removeBlur){
    $("#main").removeClass("blurred");
  }
});
```

```css
#main{
  margin:1em;
}
.blurred{
  filter: blur(2px);
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button data-target="#loginModal">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>
</button>
<section role="region">
    <div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                /* almost similar to loginModal */
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <header class="modal-header">
                        <div class="well">
                            <h2 class="modal-title">Login Formular</h2>
                        </div>
                    </header>
                    <article>
                        <div class="well modal-body">
                            /* Form */
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <a href="#" data-target="#registerModal">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<div id="main">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sollicitudin leo eu bibendum aliquam. Curabitur aliquet eros lectus, et molestie nisi tempor vel. Quisque mollis, sapien hendrerit accumsan pellentesque, quam quam vestibulum orci, nec ornare diam turpis ut purus. Cras ut quam ut nibh sollicitudin scelerisque. Nunc volutpat mauris sed porta lacinia. Vivamus pharetra eget tortor nec venenatis. Vivamus nec velit ut felis consectetur ullamcorper. Suspendisse id dictum enim. Nulla ut volutpat nisi, vitae tempor diam. Proin mattis dui ante, fermentum lacinia ex vulputate at. Donec tristique eget urna vel convallis. Mauris ac elit ut orci pretium faucibus ac sit amet justo.
</p>
<p>
Suspendisse gravida sodales lorem, sit amet posuere nunc semper et. Proin euismod at arcu in suscipit. Quisque eu efficitur nunc, quis hendrerit orci. Mauris a erat quis ante aliquam imperdiet posuere ac dui. Nam sit amet consectetur nunc. Donec risus ex, convallis eget orci tristique, rhoncus auctor tortor. Aliquam sit amet fermentum nisl. Morbi vel ipsum et nisl tristique fringilla nec sed ipsum. Aenean aliquet purus id bibendum tempus. Suspendisse auctor pretium augue, a tincidunt sapien vehicula quis. Ut eu sagittis turpis. Nulla rhoncus felis nibh, in viverra magna sagittis congue. Integer tempus ultricies viverra. Sed a aliquet velit.
</p>
<p>
Cras sagittis, dolor accumsan commodo condimentum, tellus lorem bibendum diam, in consequat augue quam nec est. Quisque id eros tortor. Ut ex risus, vehicula quis cursus a, efficitur convallis erat. Maecenas egestas lobortis maximus. Phasellus varius, ipsum in maximus ultrices, orci lectus tincidunt magna, vel vestibulum urna turpis ac leo. Nulla nulla massa, consequat non vulputate imperdiet, volutpat dapibus orci. Etiam consequat volutpat est, id tempus turpis venenatis vitae. Praesent arcu erat, porta molestie neque non, ultrices dignissim sem. Suspendisse potenti. Duis nec mauris commodo libero maximus egestas. Sed laoreet maximus tellus semper accumsan.
</p>
<p>
In hendrerit molestie blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam in ipsum urna. Maecenas in ante nisi. Integer porta molestie enim, sit amet scelerisque mauris fringilla elementum. Phasellus at elit mattis, scelerisque ligula et, imperdiet leo. Suspendisse nec dignissim augue. Cras neque turpis, tempus vel tortor sit amet, commodo laoreet augue. Aliquam ac dui vel lorem facilisis tristique non non urna. Cras pharetra mauris id aliquet luctus. Morbi sit amet felis a lectus maximus lacinia. Sed quam elit, imperdiet eu rhoncus in, scelerisque sed arcu. Aliquam feugiat ultrices finibus. Suspendisse a semper risus, gravida laoreet lacus. In fermentum auctor volutpat. Nullam egestas, lorem eget imperdiet semper, elit nisl aliquet neque, nec mollis erat lacus ut nibh.
</p>
<p>
Ut sit amet ex iaculis, vestibulum urna id, dictum elit. Nunc semper semper lacus at feugiat. Nam viverra orci vel risus vulputate, sed fringilla turpis ultrices. Vivamus pulvinar, mi in bibendum scelerisque, nunc augue laoreet sem, vitae posuere ipsum mauris vel turpis. Aliquam quis nulla maximus ligula eleifend aliquet ut a neque. Cras lobortis id ante quis sagittis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In maximus quam at rhoncus venenatis. Sed tempus nec urna vel tempus. Mauris aliquam, risus id mollis commodo, dolor tortor porta augue, in consequat purus velit nec ante.
</p>
<p>
Proin tempus pharetra nisl ut rhoncus. Fusce dapibus tincidunt lobortis. Donec dolor nisi, posuere ut ullamcorper a, molestie ut enim. Sed quis felis accumsan, pellentesque nunc at, vestibulum dolor. Pellentesque quis ex nec ex tincidunt sodales. Pellentesque eget justo nisl. Nullam rutrum ligula sed libero tempor ullamcorper. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam enim felis, cursus sed sem a, gravida consectetur diam. Ut accumsan diam ut tempor fringilla. Etiam at ex lacus. Morbi tortor mauris, blandit sed mi ut, eleifend tempus magna.
</p>
<p>
Maecenas at rutrum ante. Aenean eu sapien in sem hendrerit facilisis dictum vel sem. Ut laoreet ligula quis risus congue commodo. Donec tempor, turpis sollicitudin vulputate auctor, nunc mi maximus lectus, ornare lobortis metus neque a nibh. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed id tempor purus. Donec ipsum mauris, molestie at posuere non, scelerisque ac massa. Etiam scelerisque tempus ante, finibus dictum ante gravida eget. Suspendisse convallis risus vel velit ornare, vitae aliquam purus dictum. Nullam suscipit magna tellus, a accumsan elit viverra in. Etiam rutrum turpis non lorem condimentum viverra.
</p>
<p>
Maecenas cursus eros sed urna laoreet pulvinar. Sed a consectetur felis, consectetur gravida enim. Etiam varius ac ligula vel ultrices. Proin et lectus euismod, molestie purus ut, hendrerit mi. Suspendisse lobortis ipsum sem. Quisque nec augue quis lectus egestas consequat. Donec in arcu in mi feugiat congue. Nam porta augue venenatis diam auctor, quis aliquam dolor pulvinar. Sed vitae nibh nec ligula congue facilisis ac eget felis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent tellus arcu, commodo a vestibulum et, pulvinar vel lacus.
</p>
<p>
Quisque vel elit vitae turpis sollicitudin fringilla. Quisque iaculis dignissim sodales. Vivamus in nisi id turpis commodo pretium ornare ac enim. Nulla eu ex lobortis, lacinia mauris sed, consectetur diam. Donec at metus vel metus tincidunt blandit. Donec molestie purus quis sapien rhoncus euismod. Donec gravida, nunc quis consequat ornare, augue leo vestibulum eros, ac euismod lectus ex non mi.
</p>
<p>
Vestibulum quis libero sed risus consectetur porttitor sed quis nunc. Duis malesuada erat posuere erat suscipit, nec commodo augue faucibus. Nulla euismod diam eget sollicitudin fermentum. Sed ullamcorper tempus augue et tempus. Mauris non neque justo. Aenean tristique mauris nibh, sit amet lobortis est tristique ut. Aliquam nibh ex, varius vel consequat nec, vehicula non turpis.
</p></div>
```